# Formtastic and base errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

In the Formtastic docs, it talks about adding a line for base errors:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @record do |form| %>
  <%= form.semantic_errors :base %>
  ...main body of form...
<% end %>
```

It puzzles me that Formtastic would include effortless support for field-specific errors but by default, it offers no such accommodations for `base`. **1)** Do you you know what the reasons are for this?

**2)** In my situation I'd like all my forms to include base errors right after the form begins. Is there a way for me to get formtastic to do this by 'default' for all forms?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to display all base errors along with any and all errors of nested attributes:

`f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys`

Answer from:
https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/905

Answer (score 3):

In Formtastic 2.x, the semantic_errors ALWAYS includes :base.

However, I have noticed in Rails 3 (I am in Rails 3.2) that error messages from validations are not stored to base anymore, instead stored by attribute. For example, with this class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has a name attribute
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

Your @user.errors object on a failed create/update would look like this:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000 
  @base=#<User id:1, name: "">, 
  @messages={:name => ["can't be blank"]}>
```

If you were to make your form like this, it would output the error for the :name attribute.

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user do |form| %>
  <%= form.semantic_errors :name %>
  ...main body of form...
<% end %>
```

This is a mock example, but you see what I mean.

Unfortunately, there is nothing in the formtastic codebase currently that supports an "all" option with Rails 3 (again, I am using Rails 3.2)